# MongoDB Stitch - Service for Authentication and Issuing Tokens

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

As per [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/authentication/), there are several Authentication Providers which are available via SDK to authenticate a user.

Regardless of that, I have a few queries to implement `Token Based Authentication` via configuring `External Services`.

- Is there a way to create a Service to Authenticate instead of using SDK with clients. Basically, I want to create/configure a Service in Stitch which in-turn authenticate a user against the provided credential and needs to issue a JWT (similar to Custom Authentication Provider in SDK)?
- All other subsequent Service requests are requested with this token which needs to be validated by the service before responding.

The reason is, I want to have all implementations in Single Place (Stitch Services) instead of using several SDK for different clients e.g. Web, Mobile etc.

Comment: By single place implementation, are you referring to the fetching of the JWT in multiple clients instead of just using Stitch SDKs ?

Comment: Yes, I want a Custom Service to generate the JWTs for any client and don't want refer SDK in Client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a Service to Authenticate instead of using SDK with clients

Currently, no. This is because an application needs to be authenticated first before being able to utilise [Stitch Services](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/services/).

Depending on the application requirements, the application could try to use [Anonymous Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/authentication/anonymous/) to access an [External Service](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/services/#external-services) for your custom authentication. Although this means:

- You need to handle the service actions returns as authentication
- Other aspects of applications (functions, services, etc) are also available with anonymous authentication. Adjust rules appropriately.

Depending on the application use case, it's likely safer to write [Custom Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/authentication/custom/) for multiple clients.